# How to add & copy ParticleSystem attached to an existing GameObject using C# script in Unity?

Tags: unity, c#, particles, shuriken

I have a GameObject "FireBall" with a ParticleSystem attached to it. I want to add the same ParticleSystem to other GameObject "Avatar". Initially there is no ParticleSystem attached to "Avatar".

When I do this -

```
ParticleSystem fireparticlesyst = gameObject.AddComponent<ParticleSystem>();
```

It adds a ParticleSystem to "Avatar" but I want to set all the properties of this ParticleSystem to the ParticleSystem attached to "FireBall".

If I add all the properties by individually I can't set some of the properties as they are read only.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple workaround to do so is:

1- Make an empty `GameObject` with `ParticleSystem` attached.

2- Make prefab of that. Borrow that prefab as `public GameObject` in your script.

3- Instatiate as GameObject in your script.

4- Make child of `FireBall` and other `GameObjects` as well.

```
public GameObject _particleSystem;

void CreatePS()
{
    //Instantiate _particleSystem as new GameObject.
    GameObject ps = Instantiate(_particleSystem);

    // Set new Particle System GameObject as a child of desired GO.
    // Right now parent would be the same GO in which this script is attached
    // You can also make it others child by ps.transform.parent = otherGO.transform.parent;
    ps.transform.parent = transform;

    // After setting this, replace the position of that GameObject as where the parent is located.
    ps.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
}
```

Comment: GO to which I want to attach this particlesystem is a movable GO, after doing these steps the particlesystem is coming in the screen but its not moving with the GO.

Comment: Make sure in hierarchy that you have set the correct parent

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qfjedzZA check "FireBall" function

Comment: I think `ps.transform.parent = transform;` will work instead of `ps.transform.parent = transform.parent;`. It was a mistake. Check the edited answer

Comment: ok now ps is moving with the gameobject but its not really attached to it. I dont know how to explain this. At the start of the scene the "Avatar" starts at 0,2.01,0 position dropping to 0,0,0 due to gravity but the ps is still at 0,2.01,0 . When I move the "Avatar" the ps is also moving & rotating with it .I wish if I can post a video to show this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33618/discussion-between-hamza-hasan-and-shantanu-singh).

Comment: Because you assign position of `ps` to this. Try assigning `ps.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;` instead of `ps.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0,2.01f,0);`